# Driver manager for Debian Wheezy

Tags: linux, drivers, debian-wheezy

Today I installed [Debian Wheezy 7.6.0](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/7.6.0/amd64/iso-dvd/) amd64 to my laptop Asus but now I can see that the screen resolution is not as it should be the icons are too big and mouse works not exactly as expected etc

I cannot find any manager which may help me to find out what devices are still required to have drivers etc... I remember the "device manager" was in Windows XP which showed [yellow ???](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-vbDhniWRSTQ/Ui9Ywk76siI/AAAAAAAAAlA/QsGG4q0Zv4E/s1600/device_manager_xp.png) if device needs driver but what alternative Debian has? Or I need to install something additionally? If so please advice how?

I don't have KDE so I've just tried to find the [hardinfo](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=hardinfo) in gnome but I couldn't; it really absent in the sys tools... There is something wrong with version 7.6.0 or I just should install some additional packages? I found I have to turn-off my laptop manually cause of

> ACPI: Unable to load system description" on system boot

my **display** is marked as **"Unknown"** and I canot set any resolution :(

Is there a way to install Linux mint 17 ddm (device driver manager) on Debian Wheezy? I heard it supports gnome

Please advice some really easy to use none-terminal (or a very detailed terminal commands) solution cause I am just studying this OS

Comment: If you're afraid of the terminal and don't know GNU/Linux at all, you should have started with a more user-friendly distribution (let' say Ubuntu). Generally if all devices work in GNU/Linux, you don't need any specific driver, except for the graphic card: because of licensing issues, the driver packaged by default is often the open-source one, which, in most situations, performs worst than the proprietary one. You should check your distribution's documentation for an HowTo install proprietary graphic drivers, and check if you have an NVidia or AMD graphic card (not needed for Intel).

Comment: I am not afraid of terminal :) But I need detailed info what command I must input to get more or less optimal results; Concerning the video card I have the Intel's one; All Examples I saw were describing nVidia driver so I am a little confused is there the Intel's video card driver for linux-x64?

Comment: As I said, Intel cards don't need proprietary driver because Intel itself wrote the driver in Linux, so the one already installed is the optimal and all resolutions should be supported. You should be able to change it in the Gnome Control Center. About "mouse works not exactly as expected" we need more information: what's the current behavior, how do you want it.

Comment: My video card is so called "Integrated Intel® HD Graphics" as the asus.com says... I have drivers cd for win8 attached to my laptop only (I am not pretty sure how they may help me to fine the linux's ones anyway); Concerning the mouse it is the asus x551ma so the touchpad must be very sensitive 1 or 2 or 3 fingers press support etc so it really needs some special its driver I guess